# about Task Manager on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm developing a windows phone app, suppose my app is running, user click start key, my app will bring to background, then next user long press back key, the task manager will be shown. My question is here: How can update the screenshots of my app when it was brought to background? I don't want expose anything of my app outside even in the task manager, could I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can update the screenshots of my app when it was brought to background?

You cannot. And it's not a task manager, but a "fast app switch", allowing the user to easy swap between applications. The screenshot you see, will be the last screen of your application when it was in the foreground.

And your application will **not** be running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

No - you cannot change the image shown in the app switching UI. This is built in OS functionality.